# how to connect Docker compose container to mongoDB compass using thunder client

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLSRM.png)
i want to get this thunder client request result in MongoDB compass. but my MongoDb compass not shown thiss result? how to fix it?

[this is the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox3WM.png)

[Yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwbsS.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code or errors. Especially not FULL SCREEN screenshots!

Comment: I'm very sorry. This is my first time posting. An unknowing mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only use the hostname `mongo_db` when you connect to the container from another container on the Docker bridge network that docker-compose creates for you. On the bridge network you use the unmapped port number: 27017.

When you connect from the host machine, you need to use `localhost` and the mapped port number.

So you need to change your URI in Compass to `mongodb://localhost:2717/express_mongoosen`.

There's nothing wrong with mapping to port 2717 as such, so if that's intentional, then keep using it. But it does look like it might be a typo and you meant to use 27017?

Answer (score -1):

replace mongo_db:27017 by 127.0.0.1:27017 or localhost:27017 and your docker compose have incorrect port binding for mongodb

Comment: in YAML file or MongoDB compass?